# How to use efficient pattern matching to find row similarities in big data

Tags: python, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, fuzzy-comparison, record-linkage

I have a table of around 100,000 rows. This table is in an Excel file, and here is a snapshot of it:

```
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| First Name | Last Name | Sex | Age |                          Address                          |
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Parm       | Jit       | m   |  23 | palm court scoeity, RD. golf course, delhi                |
| Param      | jit       | m   |  24 | palm cort society, road golf course, delhi                |
| Pram       | Jet       | m   |  28 | palm court socityt Road golf course, Delhi                |
| Prm        | jit       | m   |  31 | society palm court, Rod. Golf coure, delhi                |
| Param      | Jeet      | m   |  33 | palm court scoety, delhi                                  |
| varun      | nagraj    | m   |  36 | Thame Square, auckland-AZ-2014                            |
| Janet      | kumar     | m   |  40 | Thame Square, auckland-AZ-2014                            |
| varun      | kumar     | m   |  42 | Thame Square, auckland-AZ-2014                            |
| Jatin      | Kakkar    | m   |  45 | Noida, near shipra mall, sectr 57, Noida, U.P.            |
| Jatin      | Kakar     | m   |  56 | Noida, near shipra mall, sectr 57, Noida, Uttar pardesh   |
| Jatin      | Kakkr     | m   |  57 | Noida, Flat no- 23, near shipra mall, sectr 57, Noida, UP |
| Janet      | Yellen    | F   |  23 | 11 CORONADO POINTELAGUNA NIGUELCA92677                    |
| Janet      | Yellen    | F   |  24 | 11 CORONADO POINTELAGUNA NIGUELCA                         |
| Janet      | Yellen    | F   |  25 | 11 CORONADO POINTELAGUNA 92677-0000                       |
| Jant       | Yelen     | F   |  26 | 11 CORONADO POINTELAGUNA NIGUELCA0000                     |
| Janet      | Yellen    | F   |  26 | 11 CORONADO POINTELAGUNA NIGUELC                          |
| Abigail    | Johnson   | F   |  24 | PRESERVE DRIVE NE, 11BELMONTMI4930                        |
| andrew     | symonds   | m   |  24 | Fame Stret, brisbane, hn 181                              |
| Angel      | Ahrendts  | F   |  26 | WYNGATE MANOR CTALEXANDRIAVA                              |
| Safra      | Catz      | F   |  26 | 31155 ZOAR SCHOOL ROADLOCUST GROVEVA22508-0000            |
| Park       | Geun-hye  | F   |  30 | CATHOLIC CHURCH RDBEACH LAKEPA                            |
| Sheryl     | Sandberg  | F   |  24 | 80164 SULTANA AVEINDIOCA92201-0000                        |
| Sheryl     | Sandberg  | F   |  24 | SULTANA AVEINDIOC                                         |
| Safra      | Catz      | F   |  26 | OAR SCHOOL ROADLOCUST GROVEV                              |
| Park       | Geun-hye  | F   |  30 | 308 CATHOLIC CHURCH RDBEACH LAKEPA18405-0000              |
| andrw      | simnds    | m   |  24 | Fame Stret, 181 HOUSE NO                                  |
| prashat    | vats      | m   |  35 | Al thei, al nzar, dubai12                                 |
| prasant    | vats      | m   |  37 | Al, al nazar, dubai23                                     |
| andrw      | simonds   | m   |  34 | Fame brisbane, 181 H.N.                                   |
| vats       | prashant  | m   |  30 | Al thei, al nazar, dubai                                  |
| vast       | prshant   | m   |  30 | al nazar, dubai, street adamifullah                       |
| prashant   | vats      | m   |  37 | Al thei, al nazar, dubai                                  |
| ram        | vats      | m   |  29 | Al thei, nazar, dubai                                     |
| Kiss       | hanes     | m   |  45 | Sydney, andrew str. 223                                   |
+------------+-----------+-----+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to find out row similarities in this data, for example, row 1 is quite similar to row 2. I have tried clustering algorithms (namely `BIRCH`, `DBSCAN`, `K means`, `Spectral` and `Markov Clustering`), but all of them take around half an hour to run on 100,000 rows before they give a memory error in `python` (since I am taking all the data on my `python` platform, my machine has a ram of `16gb`).

Should I use some better algorithm for this problem or do I need to move my data to a platform like `spark` and then work on it? If former is the case, can you help me out with some algorithm that doesn't take too much time? Please do not consider this as a theoretical question, as I am looking forward to an approach to solve a practical problem with big data.

Comment: Excel, and just 100000 records - that is not big data. It's megabytes, not exabytes...

Answer (score 1):

It does not make *sense* to use these algorithms on this data set...

First of all, always start with a sample to find out a *working* approach before considering scale. Don't waste time on scaling a non-working approach...

For the actual problem, rather than clustering I would suggest focus on *cleaning* the data. OpenRefine may be a good start.

Comment: What approach would you suggest for data cleaning?